# Error while installing "RcppArmadillo" package in R

Tags: c++, r, parallel-processing, g++, rcpp

I am using macOS High Sierra version 10.13.4. While installing "RcppArmadillo"package, I get the following two WARNING messages :

```
   checking whether /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang++ -Wall accepts -g... (cached) yes
   checking whether g++ version is sufficient... almost
   configure: WARNING: Compiler self-identifies as being compliant with GNUC extensions but is not g++.
   checking for macOS... found
   checking for macOS Apple compiler... not found
   checking for clang compiler... found
   checking for OpenMP compatible version of clang... found and suitable
   checking LAPACK_LIBS... R-supplied partial LAPACK found
   configure: WARNING: Some complex-valued LAPACK functions may not be available
```

When I type "gcc --version" on my terminal, I get

```
 Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
 Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
 Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
 Thread model: posix
 InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

And my Makevars file in R looks like:

```
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16/6.3.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
F77 = /usr/local/bin/gfortran
FC = $F77
CXX =  /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang++  -Wall
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/clang6/lib
CC=  /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang
SHLIB_CXXLD=ccache /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang++
CXX11 =  /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang++
CXX98 =  /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang++
CXX14 =  /usr/local/clang6/bin/clang++
```

How can I remove these two WARNING signs?

Comment: (Rcpp)Armadillo use on macOS is more difficult because macOS is "special". This has been discussed numerous times here and on the GitHub repo, see eg https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/223 as well https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/143 and more.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have checked all these links before I posted the question. But can't figure out what is the problem. That is why needed help

Comment: Misleading question title. These are warnings, not errors.

Comment: @mtall but for these warnings, cpp codes are not working. So, I would consider them as error.

Comment: You haven't shown how or where "cpp codes are not working". Where are the errors (not warnings) that lead to "cpp codes not working" ? If you don't have errors, what are the other indicators (example: wrong results). Warnings can occur due to multitude of reasons not related to the underlying problem.

Comment: Without the _C++_ error, we're going to be shooting fish in a barrel. In short, I think it's because you have `ccache` listed in the `~/.R/Makevars`. To simplify life, please do the following: 1. remove `~/.R/Makevars` and 2. follow http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/

Comment: @coatless, yes the cpp file does not upload because of the cache command as it can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

In short, these are *warnings* and **not** errors. Moreover, these *warnings* do **not** matter.

---

Let's talk about what each warning means...

#### First Warning

> configure: WARNING: Compiler self-identifies as being compliant with GNUC extensions but is not g++.

This is stating that the compiler defined in the `Makevars` file's `CXX` variable is *identifying* as `gcc` but is *not* the `gcc` compiler. In essence, each compiler has its own predefined header, see [Section 3.7.2 Common Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) of [The C Preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/index.html#SEC_Contents), and this check is focused on verifying that a modern `gcc` compiler is selected. However, it's hard to check the presence of a compiler if the compiler is lying about who it is.

For details on the origin, see discussion in the issue [Add a check message success in config after g++version check #183](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/183) and the commit [the default message on the g++ test](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/commit/dee02abec9aed7935971886699d0d5c1b6eaa72d#diff-67e997bcfdac55191033d57a16d1408a)).

#### Second Warning

> configure: WARNING: Some complex-valued LAPACK functions may not be available

Within this warning, there is a complaint that the underlying [Linear Algebra PACKage](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node7.html) is the same one that is shipped with *R*. Unfortunately, the LAPACK that is shipped with *R* is *severely* limited and a bit out of date. So, the check here is hoping for an *external* LAPACK being present via either OpenBLAS, Intel MKL, or ATLAS. Due to the way this check is structured, unless you are compiling *R* from source -- that is you opt not to use the binary provided by CRAN -- there is no way to avoid the hiccup.

Simply put, the CRAN binary looks for the LAPACK in a specific location. Switching to another LAPACK would require the establishment of a symbolic link to the existing lRlapack location, which is what [the check searches for](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/bb73525b0cb95808d787bb49bae4d96e0160ca6e/configure.ac#L111-L128). Though, it isn't advisable doing such a symbolic link. (Sorry vecLib lovers!)

If you are interested in compiling from source, consider viewing [Section A.3 Linear algebra](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Linear-algebra) of [R Installation and Administration](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html), which describes the procedure for using external LAPACKs.

Comment: In addition: There aren't that many use cases for complex valued LAPACK when it comes to R, so this is unlikely to cause real problems. In particular since everything should still work, only not as efficient as if the LAPACK routines where used.

Comment: @coatless, Thanks a lot!!!! will work on these and will let you know the progress.

Comment: @RalfStubner Thanks.